# How to create a javascript model to send to an MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a website served from a proprietary C++ server.
There is a standard javascript ajax function in the code but I don't want to start editing it.
The actual sending bit is as follows:

```
this.send=function(myawesomemodel)
{
 /*Code redacted for brevity*/   
 obj.req.open('POST',myawesomeurl,true);
 obj.req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
 obj.req.send(JSON.stringify(myawesomemodel));
}
```

It used to send key value pairs as a query string but now it needs to send json.
I can send this function a controller/action address (myawesomeurl) for the appropriate end point and I can send it an awesome object which will be accepted by the action as a basic C# Model (myawesomemodel):

public ActionResult myawesomeaction(MyAwesomeClass myawesomeclass)
{
}

For the .Net model:

```
public class MyAwesomeClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

How do I build a javascript object the controller will recognise please?
Here's my latest failure:

```
function MyAwesomeModel()
{
  this.A=1;
  this.B=2;
  this.C='Three';
}
```

Then:

```
var anawesomemodel=new MyAwesomeModel();
myawesomeajaxmodel.send(anawesomemodel);
```

I cannot construct the correct object in plain javascript so the mvc action registers it, what's the correct method please?

Comment: Having `content-type` as `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and `JSON.stringify()` together makes no sense. If your sending json, then the `content-type` should be `application/json;charset=utf-8` (and your model will be correctly bound)

Comment: Stephen! you absolute smasher!
This fixed everything, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with the same problem who finds this page, [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) nailed it

Change the ajax object to:

```
this.send=function(myawesomemodel)
{
 /*Code redacted for brevity*/   
 obj.req.open('POST',myawesomeurl,true);
 obj.req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
 obj.req.send(JSON.stringify(myawesomemodel));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myawesomemodel = {
    A : 1,
    B : 2,
    C : 'Three'
}
```